# Data insertion fails from CSV containing comma in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, opencsv

I have a CSV file with the records as follows 
                CUSTOMER_ID PRODUCT_ID  TIME_ID ACCOUNT_NUM LNAME   FNAME

```
            4728,   1   ,369 ,  37128682 ,  Gomez,  Joanne
```

One of the record contains a field that has  comma in between                                                            2996    ,     6  ,  550   ,    2413173   ,    Taylor,    ***Jr.,Emmett***

I have written the following java code to insert the records in the mysql database.

```
public class Test1 {

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
 try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Samesh",   "root", "root");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

         CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new        FileReader("C://Users/ODC/Desktop/out.csv"));

        String [] nextLine;

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
             stmt.executeUpdate("insert into       customer(CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,TIME_ID,ACCOUNT_NUM,LNAME,FNAME,GENDER,PRODUCT_NAME)"+"values ("+nextLine[0]+","+nextLine[1]+","+nextLine[2]+","+nextLine[3]+",'"+nextLine[4]+"','"+nextLine[5]+");
            }
}catch(Exception e)
 {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

}
```

Now when my program reads that record with comma within the field , it splits the the field as two values and my data insertion fails.

Here using replaceAll(",","") method wont help .

Can anyone help with a other workaround.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any exception if yes then show your stacktrace

Comment: The usual approach with CSV files is to enclose such values - in the csv file.

Comment: Im getting com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'July' in 'field list' , my original list is bigger than what I have shown in the code  , so once the record Jr.,Emmett , it gets split into 2 columns and rest of the columns gets shifted.

Comment: Your fields have plenty of padding, is there any change that the length of fields is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If a value have a comma within a field it has to surrounded by "field,content".

It also can be test if you create those case in Excel and save it to csv.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the generation of the csv then you have a few options.

You can either enclose each field with a special character that will not be present in any of the data fields (* for example) and you can then specify in the new CSVReader the deliminator you are using or alternatively you can separate out using tabs rather than comma's and again

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C://Users/ODC/Desktop/out.csv"), ',', '"');
```

or

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C://Users/ODC/Desktop/out.csv"), '\t');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but I have no control over generation of csv file and I have this CSV with comma seperated delimiters

Comment: The only other option then is to count the size of nextLine before attempting to insert it.  if it is greater than what you expect then you can either ignore it and move on to the next or do something to fix it before you attempt the insert

Answer (score 0):

You should never send an input file into a database without first controlling it.

If it is a one shot or manual operation, you should at least control the number of field per line, abort the entire file in case of problem (saying at what line) and let a human being edit and fix it by hand - human beings are incredibly more adaptable to unforesight things than programs.

If it is in a automated operation, you should write offending lines in a special file, insert the others and same let a human being fix the problems, and launch a separate insert after correction.

But accepting as normal input a csv file in which fields can contain the separator without using surrounding quotes is a general design error : the csv file is incorrect and should be corrected at generation level.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV source has a problem, change your csv source file as the following

```
"4728",   "1"   ,"369" ,  "37128682" ,  "Gomez,  Joanne"
```

I believe OpenCSV can handle it well.